# TypeScript Wrapper Function Inferring Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, strong-typing, type-constraints

I use a little utility/wrapper function for functions related to database operations. It should take a specific function `fn` with the type `Promise<PromiseReturnType<GENERIC>>`, then do some stuff (here: checking for connection) before executing it:

```js
// File `A.ts`
type PromiseReturnType<T = undefined> = {success: boolean, response: T } 

const DatabaseOperation = <Fn extends (...args: any) => Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>>, Data>(fn: (...args: any) => Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>>) => {

    return async function (...args: Parameters<Fn>): Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>> {
        if (!isConnected) return Promise.reject({ success: false, response: new Error("Not connected to the Database!") })

        return await fn(...args)
    }

}
```

Then I use it like:

```js
// File `B.ts`
const dbOperation = async (myArg: number): Promise<PromiseReturnType<string> => {

    return Promise.resolve({ success: true, response: `hello world ${myArg}` })

}


export default DatabaseOperation<typeof dbOperation, string>(dbOperation)
```

It works fine except the return type can not be inferred. It will be `Promise<any>` except `Promise<PromiseReturnType<string>>`.

Using that newly wrapped function will look like this:

```js
import dbOperation from "B.ts"

(function () {
   await dbOperation() // Type: dbOperation(myArg: number): Promise<any>
})()
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this or implement this better in general?

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Please share reproducible example

Comment: Adjusted my question, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```js
declare var isConnected: boolean;

type PromiseReturnType<T = undefined> = { success: boolean, response: T }

const DatabaseOperation = <Data, Fn extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>>,>(fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>>) => {

    return async function (...args: Parameters<Fn>): Promise<PromiseReturnType<Data>> {
        if (!isConnected) return Promise.reject({ success: false, response: new Error("Not connected to the Database!") })

        return await fn(...args)
    }

}

const dbOperation = (myArg: number): Promise<PromiseReturnType<string>> =>
    Promise.resolve({ success: true, response: `hello world ${myArg}` })



const fn = DatabaseOperation(dbOperation)

const result = fn(42) // Promise<PromiseReturnType<string>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211004#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFDoCbAMYBsCGUwcAboXAJYDOAwhAHb04zAYBccARhBLsPvQDc6GAE8wxAApQIAW2rAASsBgBXKPQAq44AB5NcALxxV9LADMKTDAD4jiOFVXZswKlQ7de-egBo4RFSQ9FTAHAZoqNgMVPAAIvgw%20Jz4oQDyElCJFAz2uglJ-gBi9HCgLGZUcAAUAHT1hADmHnACogDaALoAlEZ20nIKugPyocpqGtoS%20Yn4Nja%20NtXm9Bx1DVDNHG1dvYb9MqN6Iwrj6lo6M0nze3YI6HCPASrnrVSi9Nhw5qbYMDmlda1JotSSEfCyFTAKBUXQlGzdDgnULDQ6nF6TS4FOZ3VBPfGUcw1ACE1DojGYrF6RAmpWRwFqRAAVsxqkgnC43C1zPhcKF-IFgqEOEwAO5wACiUBkUGqACIAHIQeDRCl-VhwGAQTUAC2I2JSoWJct6yG6DwJjxpr3wovwFHgKyBIPN%20MikVVsTgGE4GWh2VyxmqslEAEFNiLVLJONDEXB6ajBmMMRdprEoFZGvM%20ninvTGW5eCRgGzHM5XO4ODAoKpgAK3EKwnAAAZ63C4bWi6C4DBwAAkCBD4cayGbKHN6CiMUdpWMBtSwD9WX%20DGqPqXAfoE898ECqlw8GMToALAAmXoAegv8bRKPpZ0xaermfmqCAA)

You should have to made `...args` an array  `any[]` instead of just `any`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

I was using that function in a jest test file, there I didn't work.

I did some further testing and found out that it actually worked before – sorry, didn't check that before – but only not in my test files.

Strange behavior I can not explain to me.

Comment: Interesting that the playground you shared won't work without `any[]` but my ts does execute in my environment even with the same version. What the heck TypeScript

Comment: you can share your example in codesandbox and I will take a look if it still relevant

Comment: Solved it! A ts configuration wasn't behaving as expected with jest. Sorry for that. Appreciate your help – thanks ! :)

Comment: @Isc I'm happy that you solved your problem! Consider answering your own question